# better and more reliable cookies

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cookies

I am making this website where you can register and login and I want the user to have the ability to stay logged in on a certain device ( and user if the system supports multiple users)
Now I Know this is perfectly possible with cookies, but people can easily or even accidentally remove those. So I was wondering whether there is a better method for this? ( in any web language, PHP and JavaScript or jQuery are preferred though)

thanks in advance

Comment: Persistant cookies are seriously looked down upon, but you might want to read up about `window.localStorage`, which lets you store _Strings_ locally, and read them in _JavaScript_.

Comment: I'm not sure you should want to do this. There are other ways, but those are usually regarded as malware or spyware, *not* as a nice feature of a web site. When a user deletes your site's cookies, that's an active choice and you'll only annoy them by subverting that choice.

Comment: You'd better log me out if I _decide_ to remove cookies. There are evils about like the [Evercookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie) though, only use it if you are absolutely devoid of morals.

Comment: This question reminds me of the nasty way flash user data was saved, you had to delete it manually... Which sucks...

Comment: You are never going to be able to protect users from their own stupidity, and if you try, then you're just going to drive yourself insane. Cookies themselves are easy, reliable, and work across every browser and platform. Do you *really* want to start having to worry about your auth implementation on every version of IE/FireFox/Chrome/Opera/Safari on every Desktop/Mobile/Tablet permutation of Windows/Linux/Apple?

Comment: Well I guess cookies is the way to go then

Answer (score 0):

People that easily delete cookies, should bew aware of consequences. You can use any other method like [web storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage), [flash cookies](http://www.adobe.com/security/flashplayer/articles/lso/). Even more you can combine them, but it is saved on client side and user can clear all the data as well. There is no possibility to store some data (sid, token, whatever) that cannot be removed.